# Drupal - Change 'From' name for user account pending and approval emails?

Tags: drupal

When users create an account and when the account is activated they receive emails from the site. The from name is either 'contact' or 'contact@mysite.com'. I want to keep using this email address but how can I make 'My Site Name' come up in a mail client as the 'from' name (as would happen from a gmail account, etc)? I dont mind if the site's name is used or I can manually specify a name.

Thanks

EDIT Mime Mail fixes this. I cant post as an answer yet so thats why im putting the answer as an edit for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mime Mail module give you the options to achieve this.